# RStan: Correct update for "poisson_log" function

Tags: poisson, rstan

I have been trying to get the Stan version of the old BUGS example "leuk" working, using the version from github.com/stan-dev/example-models.  The version of leuk.stan there works fine, but gives warnings that "<-", "increment_log_prob", and "poisson_log" are all deprecated.  I have edited all of the "<-" to "=", and "increment_log_prob" to "target +=", but I can't figure out what the correct replacement is for "poisson_log".  I checked with Stan Reference 2.14.0 and found the suggestion on page 490 that the new equivalent to "poisson_log" was "poisson_log_lpmf" (with changing the "," to a "|").  This is syntactically correct and runs, but gives the wrong answer.  Could someone tell me the correct replacement for "poisson_log"?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's `poisson_lpmf()`, not `poisson_log_lpmf()`. This confusion is the reason we are moving to using `_lpdf` and `_lpmf` suffixes.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Many thanks.